# JSP Recursive Import

Tags: java, jsp, include, jspinclude

I have a master JSP file that I want to import a recursive set of matching files from my web app into (they are mustache templates).

I want to do something like this:

```
<jsp:include page="**/*.mustache"/>
```

or

```
<%@ include file="**/*.mustache" %>
```

Is there any way to do that via a JSTL tag etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue with a bit of a hacky scriptlet:

```
<%
String path = pageContext.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
Collection<String> paths = new ArrayList<String>();
for (File file : FileUtils.listFiles(new File(path), new String[] { "ext" }, true)) {
    //Make the path relative
    paths.add(file.getAbsolutePath().substring(path.length()));
}
%>
<c:forEach items="<%=paths%>" var="path">
    <jsp:include page="../${path}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSTL`<c:import>`with `<c:param>` which is similar to above import statements as like in  the JSP.
The `<c:import>` tag provides all of the functionality of the  action but also allows for inclusion of absolute URLs.

we can also include those contents or files which are not a part of the current web application but lying somewhere outside the web application. So, the jstl `<c:import>` is more useful than the `<jsp:include>` .

By the following syntax

```
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
   <c:import url = "yourPage.jsp">
<c:param name = "anyParameter" value = "<h1>Here is your value</h1>"/>
```

Comment: Hmm, but I want to do this recursively through sub directories, picking up all the *.mustache files. I'm not quite getting how the syntax above is different from a simple <jsp:include page="myFile.mustache"/>?